# merge rows on SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL statement that returns 2 rows (booking days)

```
SELECT bd.ID, t.FirstName, t.Surname, 
CASE WHEN bd.BookingDuration = 3 AND CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END as 'TuesdayHourlyAM',
CASE WHEN bd.BookingDuration = 3 AND CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END as 'TuesdayHourlyAM2'
from BookingDays bd join
(
    select ID, MIN(StartTime) as minx, MAX(StartTime) as maxx
    from BookingDays
    where BookingDate = CONVERT(date, '18/06/2013', 103) and BookingType = 0
    group by ID
) 
tmin
on bd.ID = tmin.ID and bd.StartTime = tmin.minx

inner join Teachers t on bd.TeacherID = t.ID
where t.Surname = 'cairns'
group by bd.ID, bd.StartTime, bd.DayText, t.Firstname, t.Surname, bd.BookingDate,       bd.BookingDuration, bd.NoOfHours, tmin.minx, tmin.maxx
```

This returns -

[image: Screenshot of 2 rows that need merging in to one]

What I am looking for is a table with a similar format, however in 1 row:

Firstname | Surname | TuesdayHourlyAM1 | TuesdayHourlyAM1Start | TuesdayHourlyAM1End | TuesdayHourlyAM2 | TuesdayHourlyAM2Start | TuesdayHourlyAM2End

TuesdayHourlyAM1: BookingDayID
TuesdayHourlyAM2: BookingDayID
Start/End: Start and End Times for the bookings

Where AM1 is the smallest start time and AM2 is the largest start time (there will never be more that 2 booking days for this criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.FirstName, t.Surname, tmin.id as TuesdayHourlyAM1, tmin.StartTime as TuesdayHourlyAM1Start, tmin.Endtime as  TuesdayHourlyAM1End ,
tmax.id as TuesdayHourlyAM2, tmax.StartTime as TuesdayHourlyAM2Start, tmax.Endtime as  TuesdayHourlyAM2End
Teachers t inner join 
from 
(
    select top 1 id, bd.teacherID MIN(StartTime) as StartTime, endtime as Endtime
    from BookingDays  bd inner join Teachers t on bd.TeacherID = t.ID
    where BookingDate = CONVERT(date, '18/06/2013', 103) and BookingType = 0  and t.Surname = 'cairns'
    group by id,endtime, bd.teacherID
        order by StartTime asc
) 
tmin 
on  t.id = tmin.teacherID
join
(
    select top 1 id, bd.teacherID, max(StartTime) as StartTime, endtime as Endtime
     from BookingDays  bd inner join Teachers t on bd.TeacherID = t.ID
    where BookingDate = CONVERT(date, '18/06/2013', 103) and BookingType = 0 and t.Surname = 'cairns'
    group by id,endtime, bd.teacherID
    order by StartTime desc

) 
tmax
 on  t.id = tmax.teacherID
```

Comment: I can see where you are going with this and it should work, however 0 rows are returned. When I remove the top 1 from both joins, I get 2 rows of data, but the top row shows the first booking twice, then the second row shows the second booking twice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping your subquery by teacherid rather than bookingid

```
SELECT t.FirstName, t.Surname, minx as TuesdayHourlyAM1, maxx as TuesdayHourlyAM2
from BookingDays bd join
(
    select TeacherID, MIN(StartTime) as minx, MAX(StartTime) as maxx
    from BookingDays
    where BookingDate = CONVERT(date, '18/06/2013', 103) and BookingType = 0
    group by TeacherID
) 
tmin
on bd.teacherID = tmin.ID and bd.StartTime = tmin.minx

inner join Teachers t on bd.TeacherID = t.ID
where t.Surname = 'cairns'
```

Comment: This does work to a point. It removes the second row, however both AM and AM2 values are the same BookingDayID. Also, I am trying to show the BookingDayID in the 2 CASE statements so when I remove the ID from the group by, I can't display the ID? Cheers

Comment: I have edited my answer to satisfy the format you specified, ie Firstname | Surname | TuesdayHourlyAM1 | TuesdayHourlyAM2,  the bookingDayId should not matter, unless you also want that field returned in your SELECT

Comment: Thanks for this. I do apologize, I have edited my question to make clearer what the output needs to be.

Comment: Okay, i have added another answer to satisfy new column output,as it is a radical change from the original answer